# firebird set case insensitive collation

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

How can I set case insensitive collation for the whole database? 
Do I have to recreate the tables and data?

Database is firebird 2.5

Comment: I tried alter character set utf8 set default collation UNICODE_CI_AI but that does not seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from the [release notes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes251.html#rnfb25-ddl-altrchrset):

> The character set and collation of existing columns are not affected by ALTER CHARACTER SET changes.

So yes, it seems that the best way would be to recreate the database with desired [default character set and collation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes251.html#rnfb25-ddl-dftcolltn) (and / or with explicit definitions in domains).